# unity isGrounded works crazy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

hi creators I'm trying to make my first 3d game so it is going fine tell today when I decide to change the movement script
I'm checking if the player is grounded with OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll) on an empty gameObject attached to the player and it works fine and the player move like I dreamed 'but' after some random moves when testing the variable isGrounded turns false even if the player is grounded something that I'm sure about it
so her is the code I'm using on the gameObject child

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class isGrounded : MonoBehaviour
{
   public bool isgrounded=false;

   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){

      isgrounded=true;
   }

   private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col){

      isgrounded=false;
   }
}
```

and the player movement script

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moves : MonoBehaviour
{    


    GameObject cam,world;
    Rigidbody rd;
    bool moveR,moveL,jump,teleport;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       rd=GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       cam=GameObject.Find("Main Camera"); 
       world=GameObject.Find("World"); 
      
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)){
            moveR=true;
            
        } if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)){
            moveR=false;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){
            moveL=true;
            
        }if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)){
            moveL=false;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            jump=true;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)){
            jump=false;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)){
           teleport=true;
           world.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity=new Vector3(0,0,-90);
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate(){ Debug.Log(isGrounded());
        

        if(moveR==true&&isGrounded()==true){ 
                rd.velocity=new Vector3(5,0,0);
                if(jump==true){rd.velocity+=new Vector3(0,5f,0);}
                }
        
        if(moveL==true&&isGrounded()==true){ 
                rd.velocity=new Vector3(-5,0,0);
                if(jump==true){rd.velocity+=new Vector3(0,5f,0);}
                }
             

        if(jump==true&&isGrounded()==true){ 
                rd.velocity+=new Vector3(0,5f,0);
         }
}


    bool isGrounded(){
     return transform.Find("GroundCheck").GetComponent<isGrounded>().isgrounded;
    }    
       
}
```

I really want to know why and be sure I understand the mechanism of this wonderful variable isGrounded turning false while the player is grounded
and also I would like to know if there is a deference between OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerStay

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use `Find` and `GetComponent` repeatedly and especially not in `FixedUpdate` ... rather store the according reference **once** and re-use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're checking if an object is grounded via OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit.

You have no possible way to determine that correctly using this method. Instead you should use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html. You can throw the Raycast downwards, check if it hits anything that have a tag corresponding to your ground objects and if yes then you know you're on the ground.

For the second question. The difference between OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerStay is that OnTriggerEnter is only invoked when one collider enters the other. OnTriggerStay on the other hand is invoked constantly if the colliders are overlapping each other.

Comment: Some additional tip if you're seriously thinking about coding. 

Read this book - https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882 because your code looks abysmal. The way you write your code reflects on how good coder you are, and it's really important to write good looking, clean code.

Comment: thank you very much for your intention to make me a better coder ^^ I wish the world is full of people like you .. those who make this world better and better .. sincerely thank you so much